# How to add rows of tr tags in Datatables

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

According to the datatables [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) "each data element may be an array, object, Javascript object instance or a tr element." If I use ajax to return an array of strings, and then use the rows.add method, it seems to interpret every character as a cell value:

## HTML

```
<table id="dt">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 0 col 1;</td><td>row 0 col 2;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="mybutton" type='submit'>Add rows</button>
```

## JS

```
var data = ["<tr><td>row 1 col 1;</td><td>row 1 col 2;</td></tr>", "<tr><td>row 2 col 1;</td><td>row 2 col 2;</td></tr>"];

var datatable = $('#dt').DataTable();

$("body").on('click', '#mybutton', function(evt){
    console.log ("button clicked");
    datatable.rows.add(data);
    datatable.draw();   
    evt.preventDefault();
})
```

## Example output

I've created a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rachael_P/jvur4qdy/) showing this.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just make an array of values to add. Let datatable create the tr,td, etc

Comment: your button type is submit when it should be 'button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code is changing the HTML directly, you need to destroy and rebuild the datatable for it to show up in the data object.  This code does that.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var md = ["<tr><td>row 1 col 1;</td><td>row 1 col 2;</td></tr>", "<tr><td>row 2 col 1;</td><td>row 2 col 2;</td></tr>"];

            var datatable = $('#dt').DataTable();


            $('#mybutton').on('click', function (evt) {
                datatable.destroy();
                $.each(md, function (i, item) {

                    $('#dt tbody').append(item)
                });
               datatable = $('#dt').DataTable();

            })

        });
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would not normally add the html to the data as mentioned above. Just pass in the data. However, if you have actual reason to do it this way, here is one way that works.

```
var data = ["<tr><td>row 1 col 1;</td><td>row 1 col 2;</td></tr>", "<tr><td>row 2 col 1;</td><td>row 2 col 2;</td></tr>"];

var datatable = $('#dt').DataTable();

$('#mybutton').on('click',  function(evt){
  $.each(data, function(i, item){$('#dt tbody').append(item)});
  datatable.rows.invalidate().draw()
})
```

Comment: Many thanks. This does display the new rows, but it doesn't seem to include them in the data structure properly, as the datatables information still says "0 rows" and the search doesn't find any contents.

I am still puzzled by the comment in the documentation which suggests I should be able to use the rows.add() function with tr tags, but I think I'll pursue your other suggestion.

Comment: This code works because of an error. My bad, ignore it

Answer (score 0):

This is actually how I would do it.

```
var data = [["row 1 col 1","row 1 col 2;"],[ "row 2 col 1;", "row 2 col 2;"]];

var datatable = $('#dt').DataTable();

$('#mybutton').on('click',  function(evt){
  datatable.rows.add(data).draw()
})
```

Comment: I can see that this solution works, but my problem with this approach is that it means structuring the entire script around producing table data in datatables-friendly format. What I really like about datatables is the ability to access most of the functionality with a single jQuery function call, which means you can add it as an afterthought (which is what I was doing).

Comment: Actually, this is more realistic. Basically all you have to do is pull the data out of the database, put it into an array or an array of objects and send it to the client. From that point, DataTable will do the heaving lifting.